# Data scale for regression analysis

Tags: estimation, dataset

I am working on my PhD thesis.i have dependent variable as daily stock return for many firms and independent variable are inflation, exchange rate etc.
My problem is 
1-my dependent variable stock return is on daily basis for whole month but independent variable are on monthly basis
2-stock return of firms i.e dependent variableAll firms under consideration have different no of observation for share prices as every firm does not trade on daily basis.some firms have 10 observation in a months some have 20 some have 5 some have just 2.

My problem is how can I compare them when I'm having on one side only one observation of independent variable and on other side have 20 observation for dependent variable.
How can I bring them on same scale
Thanks
Umer

Comment: You could average all variables over the whole month. For those that are updated daily you could also study their moments: e.g., variance over the month.

Comment: Thanks for your help but taking avg prices for shares is not acceptable method. One way is by using mixed data sampling but that is use for independent variable.my problem is with dependent variable.is there any method like mixed data sampling that can help me to convert my high frequency data of dependent variable on the same low frequency scale as of independent variable.